# Hide button in another cell when cell is tapped

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView with three cells. In two of them I have a button. I would like to hide the button in the other cell, when one of the cells is tapped.

I have tried some solutions in `didSelectRowAt` but have not been able to hide the buttons:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ComposeCell1 {
           cell.compose.isHidden = true
        if let cell2 = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ComposeCell2 {
            cell2.compose.isHidden = true //I can reach the cell from here, but its not hiding the button
            }

            }
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ComposeCell2 {
                cell.compose.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to track the index for the pressed button with a variable. And use the variable in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell to update the button's visibility. Only thing you need to do in didSelectRowAt is assign the index value the variable and reload the table view

```
var selectedIndex: Int?

....

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   .....
   cell.compose.isHidden = indexPath.row != selectedIndex
   .....
   return cell

}
```